# Matplotlib add color legend with value based on another variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to add color legend like this:

```
Green - Tier 1
Gold - Tier 2
Silver - Tier 3
Chocolate - Tier 4.
```

The values 'Tier 1', 'Tier 2', 'Tier 3', 'Tier 4' are based on another column called `RFM['Tier']`.

```
plt.style.use('classic')
#Scatter plot monetary and recency
Color = ['green','gold','silver','chocolate']
RFM['Color']= RFM['Cluster'].map(lambda p: Color[p])
ax = RFM.plot(
    kind='scatter',
    x='Monetary', y='Recency',
    figsize=(10,8),
    c= RFM['Color']
)
ax.set_title('Monetary and Recency Distribution',color='darkslategray')
```

[image: Scatter Plot of Monetary and Recency]

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I changed the Tier values. You can post an official answer afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seaborn's `scatterplot` would automatically create a legend. The `hue=` tells which column to use for coloring, the `palette=` parameter tells the colors to use (either a list or a colormap). For non-numeric data, `hue_order=` can fix a certain ordering.

Here is an example with toy data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('classic')
N = 100
RFM = pd.DataFrame({'Tier': np.random.randint(1, 5, N),
                    'Monetary': np.random.uniform(1, 100, N),
                    'Recency': np.random.uniform(1, 500, N)})
color_palette = ['green', 'gold', 'silver', 'chocolate']
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=RFM, x='Monetary', y='Recency', hue='Tier', palette=color_palette)
ax.set_title('Monetary and Recency Distribution', color='darkslategray')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To change the legend labels, `ax.legend` can be called explicitly, e.g.:

```py
ax.legend([f'Tier {i}' for i in range(1, 5)])
```